# How much of powdered rennet should I use when making mozzarella out of 2 liters of unpasteurized milk?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

I bought a bottle of powdered rennet as shown in the image but without a manual on how to use.

https://m.imgur.com/a/flFKwKp

I am learning how to make cheese, and I have a local store who sell unpasteurized milk. So my first attempt is going to be on mozzarella.

I have 2 litres of milk. How much of citric acid and rennet powder should I dilute in water for the 2 liters.

My second question, if by mistake, used an excess amount of rennet, is there a risk of poisoning ?